# find out how much free RAM required to render the page

Tags: javascript, css, html

Is there a way to find out how much free RAM required to render the page?

My boss wants a "minimum requirements" information.

The application is a large system with javascript and Java Applet.

I already tested how much the Java Applet need, but I want to know how much is required for the webpage.

I looked the "TaskManager" of chrome, can I be sure that the necessary RAM will be the same on  poor computers?

Comment: If you need to ask, the page is probably too big. The answer also depends ENTIRELY on the browser's internal workings, and therefore can't be answered in general, just specifically "In FF it takes X megabytes, in Safari it takes Y, in Chrome it takes Z, in Lynx it takes 10kb", blah blah blah.

Comment: What is your motivation, why do you want to know this?

Comment: my boss want me to do a "minimum requirements" thread on the FAQ page

Comment: In that case i'd list the minimum requirements for the browser itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tell your boss RAM is not a relevant indicator for a website.

These are good requirements you can list :

- Minimum version for each browser (e.g : Firefox 3+, IE 7+, Safari 4+...). For these, you just have to tes our website.
- Javascript enabled on your browser
- Java/Flash/Silverlight/Other plugin required ?
- You can specify OS, but normally all OS must be compatibles: Windows, MacOS, Linux

If your boss really doesn't understand, just put standard value : like 500Mb for RAM or just look at the minimum requirements of the browsers themselves.

Answer (score 0):

No, this is ridiculous. You dont want nor need this, at all.

First of all RAM isnt the only statistic you might want to measure, and its not like its going to be the limiting factor. Second it really, really depends on what OS/Browser/RAM type the user is using.

Comment: how are you so sure about what I need?

Comment: Can you explain your scenario, why exactly do you want to know this statistic? Because i cant think of anything.

Answer (score 0):

Chrome will show the memory consumed per tab in chrome://memory-redirect/

Comment: yes. i know. but I have a good computer, I would like to know how much it will use if it wasnt that good

Comment: @melanke: Get a bad computer and try it.

Comment: What does the kind of computer (bitness aside) have to do with anything?

Answer (score 0):

Technically, no, but I would imagine it is related to the content you're loading, and what the code is doing. Ex: large images and JS objects would eat up more memory space.

Answer (score 0):

The minimum requirements of a web site are expressed in terms of technology support, not RAM, CPU or disk space as in desktop apps. Just add the list of browsers where it's been tested.

Answer (score 0):

Any browser has minimal system requirements, use those.